# CMake: configure_file() does not touch if the file is the same?

Tags: cmake

By checking the timestamp of a sample file `out.txt` before and after running `configure_file(in.txt out.txt)`, it seems like the last modified date does not change when the new content is the same when the `out.txt` file already exist (so when variables are the same).

Is it really true and guaranteed? I can't find about this in CMake documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really true and guaranteed? I can't find about this in CMake documentation.

You have partly answered your own question here: if it's not documented, it's certainly not guaranteed. Fortunately, it *is* documented, here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html

> If the input file is modified the build system will re-run CMake to re-configure the file and generate the build system again. The generated file is modified and its timestamp updated on subsequent cmake runs only if its content is changed.

Internally, `configure_file` writes its output to a temp file and then calls the equivalent of `cmake -E copy_if_different`. That is, it does a byte-for-byte comparison and only does the copy (thereby updating timestamps) if there is a difference.

You can see the sources here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/f0a2ec12e2743a7be39201e2bc563ab37debd791/Source/cmMakefile.cxx#L3836

Comment: It is documented actually. In the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) see the sentence "The generated file is modified and its timestamp updated on subsequent cmake runs only if its content is changed."

Comment: @Tsyvarev - thanks for catching that! I had taken OP at their word.